# Adding columns dynamicly by query in MS SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have two tables in SQL Server 2012.

**TableA**

[image]

Now I want to add TableA's (Name) rows at TableB as varchar(150) Column. Result will like below:

**TableB**

[image]

How can I do this?

Comment: Do you want to add new columns in `TableB` based on rows in `TableA`? can you explain the need of why you want to do something like this

Comment: This is called a `crosstab`. Try searching on this and you will find many many solutions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add columns dynamically using below code, basically I am building dynamic ALTER TABLE statement to add multiple columns at once.

```
 CREATE TABLE TableA (NAME Varchar(10), NameTYPE varchar(20))
    INSERT INTO TableA VALUES ('A','Excellent'),('B','Good'),('C','Poor')

    CREATE TABLE TableB(ID INT, FullName Varchar(20), Gender Char(2))

-- Check Table Column
    SELECT * FROM TableB


    DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

    select @cols = STUFF((SELECT  ',' + QUOTENAME(NAME)  +' Varchar(150)' 
                        from TableA
                        order by NAME
                FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
                ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
            ,1,1,'')

    set @query = 'ALTER TABLE dbo.TableB Add ' + @cols 

    Exec (@Query)

-- Check Table Column
    SELECT * FROM TableB
```

Comment: can u please check each column if exists then do not add else add the column?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
declare @Rows int = 1
declare @colName nvarchar(150)
declare @Id int = 0
declare @MySql  nvarchar(max)


set @MySql = 'select  Id, FullName,Gendar, '

select  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Name DESC) AS 'Id', Name  into #dt from TableA

WHILE @Rows>0
BEGIN

    SELECT top 1  @Id = Id, @colName =Name FROM #dt where Id >@Id

    set @Rows =@@RowCount
    if @Rows>0
    begin
        set @MySql = @MySql +   @colName     + ' ,'
    end

END
set @MySql = substring(@MySql,0,(len(@MySql)-1)) +' from TableA'
select @MySql
```

Answer (score 0):

you should be sure Name columns is not dublicate

```
select  distinct Name  into #dtTemp from TableA
select  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Name DESC) AS 'Id', Name  into #dt from #dtTemp
```

Comment: I do not understand why this question has received 3 minus votes? What I wanted was clearly described.